# Pass pointer to int*& and get compiled error

Tags: c++

Why does `fun(p)` work and `fun(&i)` does not?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void fun(int*& pp) 
{ 

} 

int main()
{
    int i;

    int *p;

    fun(p);

    fun(&i); // not working... why?
}
```

Comment: SO questions should be self-contained, please include the code in the question rather than having an external link

Comment: because the adress of i, `&i` can only be given by rvalue and you cannot pass a rvalue by reference. Whereas `p` being a pointer, the adress p holds is an `lvalue`

Comment: @user addresses are not lvalues per se . and you can pass rvalues by rvalue reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int* & pp` means that the function parameter is a non-const lvalue reference. Which means the argument must be an lvalue.

`&i` is not an lvalue , therefore it is not a valid argument for a non-const lvalue reference.

Answer (score 1):

lvalue references to non-const cannot bind to prvalues.

if you change the type of the reference to rvalue reference or lvalue reference to const, the code will compile.